# Basic Token authentification and authorization on Web.Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

So I have an MVC Application that calls WebApi method.

My Authorization on MVC App is done like this

```
  public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

        private RolesEnum _role;

        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute() {
            _role = RolesEnum.User;
        }

        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(RolesEnum role) {
            _role = role;
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {

            User currentUser = (User)httpContext.Session["CurrentUser"];

            if (currentUser == null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (currentUser.Role == RolesEnum.User && _role == RolesEnum.Admin) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

The authentification is done calling a WebApi method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {

        User acc = new User();
        acc.Username = username;
        acc.Password = password;
        acc = accBL.Login(acc);

        if (acc != null) {
            Session.Add("CurrentUser", acc);
            return  RedirectToAction("Index", "Project", null);
        } else {
            return View();
        }


    }
```

Login method looks like this

```
  public User LogIn(User acc) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                   new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/Login", acc).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>().Result;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

            } catch {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And WebApi method looks like this

```
 [Route("api/Account/Login")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Login(User userModel) {
            User user = db.Users.Where(p => p.Username == userModel.Username && p.Password == userModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null) {
                return Ok(user);
            } else {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }

        }
```

How can I make a connection between the MVC App and the WebApi Services. My authorization and authentification works on MVC part, but my WebApi Services can be called without this any authorization/authenification. How can I secure my WebApi too based on my example? I've been working for about 3 weeks with MVC and WebApi and many things are not very clear too me.

Should I just create a GUID in  public IHttpActionResult Login(User userModel) and check for it everytime i a method is called? How do i pass this GUID to MVC App and from MVC to WebApi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create some sort of a token (eg. JWT) in the WebAPI `Login()` method and return with the `Ok()` response (to the MVC app). Users calling your API endpoints have to send this token back (eg. in a custom "Token" header). You can validate the token inside a custom WebAPI authorize attribute that you use in your API endpoints.

eg.

**Login endpoint**

```
[Route("api/Account/Login")]
[HttpPost]
public object Login(User userModel) {
    User user = ...;
    string token = CreateTokenForUser(user);

    if (user != null) {
        // return user and token back 
        return new {User = user, Token = token};
    } else {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

**Custom authentication filter**

```
public class UserAuthAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string token = null;
        IEnumerable<string> tokenHeader;
        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Token", out tokenHeader))
            token = tokenHeader.FirstOrDefault();

        if (token != null && IsTokenValid(token)
        {
            // user has been authenticated i.e. send us a token we sent back earlier
        }
        else 
        {
            // set ErrorResult - this will result in sending a 401 Unauthorized
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult(Invalid token", context.Request);
        }
    }

}
```

**Other endpoint which only authenticated users should be allowed access**

```
[Route("api/Values")]
[HttpGet]
[UserAuth]
public object GetValues() {

    // only requests with a valid token will be able to call this because of the [UserAuth] attribute
}
```

Comment: I'll test it in a few! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I've accepted the answer, i took some of the things you've posted and made some modifications. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution! The ideas I posted are from a already functioning bigger project...

Comment: Yeah, what I've change it that I send the token from api to client using Headers and not the content and I pass the UserModel into the content.